# MaterialTextView shapeAppearanceOverlay not working

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, android-shapedrawable

I am trying to achieve a simple rounded corner layout with a colored background on two specific MaterialTextViews. Codes are below:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
    android:id="@+id/lblStartTime"
    style="@style/customTimeRangePickerStyle"
    android:layout_width="68dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<style name="customTimeRangePickerStyle" parent="">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/customTimeRangePickerDay</item>
</style>

<style name="customTimeRangePickerDay" parent="">

    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">4dp</item>

    <item name="strokeWidth">1dp</item>
    <item name="strokeColor">@color/Cor2</item>

    <item name="android:background">@color/fieldBackground</item>
</style>
```

Any tips why this is not working? The resulting textview shows no borders nor background color.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (`1.3.0`) the `MaterialTextView` doesn't use a `MaterialShapeDrawable` and **doesn't support** the `ShapeAppearanceModel` and `shapeAppearance/shapeAppearanceOverlay` attributes.

More info a about the supported components in t[he doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md#supported-components).

However you can apply a `MaterialShapeDrawable`:

```
      <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
          android:id="@+id/textview"
          android:paddingLeft="8dp"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
          android:text="Text"
          />
```

and:

```
val radius = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.default_corner_radius)

val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview)
val shapeAppearanceModel = ShapeAppearanceModel()
    .toBuilder()
    .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, radius)
    .build()

val shapeDrawable = MaterialShapeDrawable(shapeAppearanceModel)
shapeDrawable.setStroke(2.0f, ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.red600));
ViewCompat.setBackground(textView, shapeDrawable)
```

[image]

You can also build the `ShapeAppearanceModel` using an overlay defined in the theme. Just use in the code above:

```
 val shapeAppearanceModel =
            ShapeAppearanceModel.builder( context,
                    R.style.ShapeAppearance_MaterialComponents_SmallComponent,
                    R.style.shapeAppearanceOverlay)
            .build()
```

with:

```
<style name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">xxx</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriele, I missed that point. This would not solve my current issue, though. The reason I tried the overlay is because I need to be able to change the background drawable shape for Day/Night themes compatibility and was not willing to create two different drawables for that. Any suggestions?

Comment: @IlianFelinto I've updated the answer. You can build the `ShapeAppearanceModel` using an `shapeAppearanceOverlay` defined in the style. In this way you can define it in the day/night theme files.

Comment: I have changed the object type to MaterialButton and now I can see the correct shape. But it totally ignores the strokeColor, strokeWidth and background(color) items. Also, is the only way to do it is programatically, or the property "style" is ok on the xml definition file?